# Is it correct to say "I slump/slumped on/onto the stool/barstool?"

Tags: word-usage

I wrote this sentence: "I buy a bottle of beer and slump on/onto the last stool."

A native English speaker told me that "slump" doesn't work here. That you can't slump on a bar/barstool.

Is this correct? If so, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you "slump on a bed" or "slump onto a bed?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/185826/do-you-slump-on-a-bed-or-slump-onto-a-bed)

Comment: Of course you can slump onto a stool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of **slump** is fine and fits with the definition of the [verb form](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slump).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the native English speaker I mentioned is wrong?

Comment: @alexchenco I suppose so. Here is the example from the dictionary I linked: "Exhausted, he slumped down into the chair."

Comment: No. Slumping down into a chair is entirely possible. Slumping on a stool is not. There's no sides or back on a stool; one must balance on a stool, and has nothing to slump on, in, onto, or into. One would slide off a stool if one tried to slump on it.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't see anything in the definition that would make it impossible to slump on a stool. Nowhere does the definition mention that you must be leaning against the back or side of anything to slump. If you can slump standing, why would you not be able to slump sitting in a stool?

Comment: Definitions in a dictionary do not constitute the language. One must especially not conclude, from what is **not** included in a dictionary definition, that something is not included in the meaning of a word. Depend on native speakers. For instance, for some information on _slump_ that you won't find in a dictionary, check out the phonosemantics of the [`SL-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sl.pdf) and the [`-UMP` rime](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ump.pdf)  in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler Those links are great resources. However, I don't see anything in there that indicates that one cannot slump in a stool. I am a native speaker, and I see nothing wrong with that usage. Feel free to provide an alternative answer explaining why that would be impossible.

Comment: Stools have no sides; there must be 2-dimensional contact to slump. One can slouch on a stool, because that involves posture, but slumping is essentially what loose cement does when it's mounded into a hill -- it just moves down away from the highest point. That's the SL- part; liquid-solid interfaces like cement are common with SL- words. With a human body the closest you can come is to hunker down and become an UMP, which requires something to brace the slumping body. Think of beanbag chairs, or even worse, hung fabric chairs; those are for slumping into.

Comment: @JohnLawler I understand your point; I just don't see it the same way. You are welcome to add an alternative answer.