# Do you "slump on a bed" or "slump onto a bed?"

Tags: word-choice

Is one of them the correct option? Or they mean different things?

On Google maps I got these results:

["slumped on the bed"](http://%22slumped%20on%20the%20bed%22) (9K results)

["slumped onto the bed"](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=AeL&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&ei=n7nuW5TXJIGk8QXYhbWwAw&q=%22slumped%20onto%20the%20bed%22&oq=%22slumped%20onto%20the%20bed%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...16904.17165.0.17381.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.av4hOqnzyqQ) (3K results)

Example sentence:

> Without permission, he slumped on/onto my bed and lay on his back.

Comment: Your first link doesn't work. But simply counting hits like that often won't tell you diddly.  You have to read the attestations and determine the meaning from context to see if there's a reason for the choice of the one or the other preposition.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you slump onto (bed or bar stool). The verb is still the same and still acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either.

To slump is to ease from an erect posture to a relaxed one where the shoulders are hunched and there can also be a bend at the waist.

If you slump *on* the bed, you're on the bed, slumping.

If you slump (down) *onto* the bed, you come to rest on the bed as the end result of your slumping.

That's the basic difference of **on** and **onto**.

But some speakers may use **on** to mean **onto**.

> He jumped on the stairs of the train as it began to pull out of the station.
>
> He jumped onto the stairs of the train as it began to pull out of the station.

So, given this variation in usage in the speaking population, you cannot be sure exactly what is meant if the preposition is **on** in this context.